# Infinite Vertical Scrolling in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, vertical-scrolling

While I try to use scrolling background vertically, the patches appear while scrolling vertically.

Can you explain me why? If the background is scrolling horizontally it works fine!

Maybe due to lighting problems.

**Scroll Script:**

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Scrollscript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float scrollSpeed = 0.2f;
    private Renderer rend;
    private Vector2 offset;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() {
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() { 
        offset = new Vector2(0, Time.time * scrollSpeed);
        rend.material.mainTextureOffset = offset;
    }
}
```

[image: Please see the patch]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the image so that it fits with its copy on horizontal and vertical.
i.e looping of an image should be created so that when the image scrolls for second time, it is not noticed. This is something you need to solve in photoshop or some other photo editing software rather than unity.